# LCMS/MS versus Western Blot

Tags: proteins, lab-techniques, western-blot, methods

I have a general question regarding which method would you recommend me to use if I would like to investigate the difference in the level of several proteins in tissue samples and compare different treatment groups. I could either do an LCMS/MS or a Western blot. Which one would you recommend and would you do both for validation? I am looking for time- and cost-effective techniques. 
I'll appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: How would you prep the tissue for LCMS/MS? That read out would totally look like garbage. There are all sorts of tricks for western blot that you could get an accurate measure. Personally, I would do ELISA to quantitate how much protein you actually have.

Comment: Which quantification do you need, absolute,  relative, or semi? Usually semi-quantification would be enough.

Comment: [Related post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26028/mass-spectrometry-versus-western-blotting-for-validation)

Answer (score 3):

Western blot, though is a commonly used technique and is relatively simple to do, has some issues:

- Low throughput: it is difficult to analyse multiple proteins simultaneously
- Limited cross comparability: since antibodies to different proteins can have different affinities, they cannot be compared with each other.
- Low sensitivity
- Not very quantitative

LCMS addresses all the above limitations of western blot. It is also possible to do [targeted proteomics](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v10/n1/full/nmeth.2285.html) i.e. study just some few proteins instead of the entire proteome.
An LCMS system has a high initial setting up cost but a relatively lower run cost. However, the mass spectrometer has to be maintained and it is not an easy job; you basically need a facility and a dedicated technical staff.

> Which one would you recommend and would you do both for validation?

Which technique to use depends on what you really want to see and what resources you have at hand. It is a commonly practised approach to do a western blot for re-validating a few selected genes identified from LCMS experiment, which is just to prove that the result can be obtained using another technique too.

Answer (score 1):

Although quantitative methods using MS have been developed, MS is not inherently quantitative. Quantification with MS could be quite tricky. Therefore, it is not the first choice. But, if you do not know which protein levels change and want to find proteins the expression levels of which are different between your samples you are going to compare, MS is not bad idea. In this case, validation is necessary. In other words, MS is not used to validate WB results in general.

In your case, you know which proteins you want to see. Therefore, I would suggest WB. This is a more direct way. Validation of WB may not be necessary, but it is better to get some supportive data: the protein activities in lysates, mRNA levels, etc.

Comment: MS=Mass Spectro**metry**; the name itself implies quantification. When you say it is not so quantitative, what are you comparing it with?

Comment: Peptides are ionized to determine the mass and ionization efficiency is not predictable. It would depend on peptide sequences and probably environments surrounding peptides. I think the word spectrometry in MS is used because you can see spectrum of molecular mass.

Comment: Ionization and fragmentation techniques are quite standardized. All quantification techniques suffer from some kind of bias. Western blot also suffers from biases.

Comment: Western blotting and mass spec each have their pros and cons. If you're doing a targeted analysis of a particular protein and have antibodies available (especially commercially available antibodies) I would suggest doing a Western blot. This is a much older technique and people are likely more comfortable with it. In my opinion, it's also much more comforting being able to compare relative densities on a blot visually than looking at mass spec output.

Comment: @VanceAlbaugh The only advantage of western blot is that it is easier to do and most people are comfortable with it. As you said, it is certainly cost-efficient and easy when only a few proteins are to be studied. However, even in this case cross comparisons are difficult. Antibody-protein interactions for different pairs are not comparable. It can be much more biased than fragmentation/ionization bias in MS.

Comment: @ WYSIWYG ionization efficiencies for fragmented peptides also vary very much. I though this makes cross comparisons difficult as well.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Although ionization techniques are standardized, comparison of two samples would be difficult when MS is performed in the same way but separately. Even if solution eluted at the same time from LC, ionization efficiency seems to vary. To improve this, mixing both sample to analyze them in same solution is designed. I'll write it in the next comment.

Comment: To improve this, mixing both sample to analyze them in same solution is designed. This ways, everything is the same exactly except for from which sample the peptides derived from. To recognize peptides from which sample, samples has to be labeled. Stable isotope labeling metabolically results in several molecular mass shift (or depend on which isotope and how many atoms)mass shift). This makes comparison more reliable. There are other ways to label, but they seem less quantitative.

Comment: What I am saying is that, despite all the possible problems you that mention, western blot is much more unreliable than MS. In MS ionization efficiency may vary but there are ways to detect multiply charged species (it also depends on ionization method and IMO only ESI has a high likelihood of producing multiply charged species). In western there is no way to compare two antibodies unless you make a standard curve (which I don't think anyone does).

Comment: @WYSIWYG (which I don't think anyone does)>It is because they do not think it is necessary. Because different proteins have different activities. Comparison of the actual amounts between different proteins is less informative unless you are studying stoichemistry of components in some protein complexes. Even if cell lysates has protein complexes and you want to see one of the components, cells may not form the complexes by some regulations.

Comment: @WYSIWYG (In MS ionization efficiency may vary but there are ways to detect multiply charged species> Ok, then here is my question. Then why scientists have to desperately develop quantification methods, utilizing stable isotopes etc.

Comment: Western blot is an old technique. MS has been relatively recently developed for proteomics so a lot of advancement is still going on. Stable isotope labelling helps in differentiating samples  quantified **in the same run** (test vs treated). At least I know this is so for SILAC and ITRAQ. I said standard curve is necessary for WB because there is no way you can compare two different antibody labels from the same blot. This is turning into a huge discussion and perhaps we should discuss this in chat.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So I have access to both techniques, for LCMS there is a trained technician that could sort out any problems arising from the procedure. It is not clear yet whether it would be better to use one or the other, or necessarily both. I will need to detect changes in targeted proteins but also it would be nice to see changes in other unknown proteins. So with LCMS I could achieve this, but would it be necessary to confirm it with Western blot? Thanks!

Comment: Many people use LCMS for comprehensive, exhaustive  proteome analyses then assess the results with some other ways. Especially WB is popular for this assessment. Various steps are involved in MS data process because coverage of peptides is not 100%, some proteins share the same peptides, and modification disturbs peptide identification. I would say MS is not straightforward. WYSIWYG may know the way using only MS. You could also ask people in the facility you are going to use if the ability of the MS there could achieve satisfactory results to publish only MS.

Comment: If you are going to do bioinformatic analyses using whole data, you do not need to assess all proteins. But you might want to pick up several to show the MS is working well.

Comment: @Mary It is good to confirm the results using another technique and I guess there is no other technique that is more popular/easy-to-do than westerns. MS is data intensive and doing replicates would be time consuming. You can do multiple replicates in WB. So the general idea is: do LCMS → identify important proteins → Do WB for them.

Comment: @243 I am not disagreeing with you. MS analysis has problems and new algorithms are being developed for better reliability. What I am saying is that WB does not necessarily address the issues that MS has. The only advantage is that it is easy to do (sometimes that also can be problematic if you don't have the antibodies).

Comment: @Mary If you found your answer then please accept it. In general if you find a post useful then you can upvote it. (Check the buttons on the top left side  of the posts)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use FPLC if you know what kind of protein you're looking for.in case you don't know what are you looking for,then you can run a 2D-PAGE and after analyzing spots then use LC MS/MS to identify your proteins and then continue with FPLC ( for record FPLC is a method of HPLC or LC which is protein friendly and even you can use it to isolate and purify your chosen protein )